# C# Change datagridview row value by dragging on treeview node

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, drag-and-drop, treeview

I want to drop datagridview rows in the nodes of a treeview for changing its specific value. Ive read a plenty of Tutorial but didnt find what i need/got it in my own.
My Applikation Downloads a txt File and reads it into a treeview with 5 parentnodes, they are similiar to the columns in the datagridview. The normal nodes keep the Same values Like the rows.
I want to be able to drop a row on a treeview node for example 'parentnode1''childnode3' and Change the row value of 'column1' to'childnode3.value'
Hope you can Help :)

Comment: I looked at something similar earlier this year and it was complicated.  It may be better to move data into a different type object that looks like a DGV row.  I like looking at Code Projects for creating custom objects.  See : https://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. - It shouldn't be too hard. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Ive edited the original question. I accomplished to add my rows to the treeview as a node ans troed to Change it Foto the way i need i to work